# How to display custom field value on index loop?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, rating

I want to display rating on single post type and same rating value I want to show on index page, where all post types are listing. On the index page:
[image]

Please, check the rating on [single post](https://desigoa.com/tours/snorkeling/) (at the bottom). Also, see here:
[image]

Here are code of custom fields:

```
  <?php
    //grab the rating value
     $rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);

//prints star image
for ($i=1; $i<=$rating; $i++){
    echo '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
}

//prints unstar image
for ($i=$rating; $i<5; $i++){
    echo '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
}
?>
```

Please, advice.

Comment: what is wrong with your code? what advice do you want to get?

Comment: code are okey no issue, just want to display same rating on index page. same how rate are showing with product everywhere